# Mysql Select & order on 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL. I have a table with the following structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(255), `post_id` int, `type` varchar(255) )
;

INSERT INTO posts
    (`id`, `title`, `post_id`, `type`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Hello', NULL, 'post'),
    (2, 'This is title', NULL, 'post'),
    (3, NULL, 1, 'like'),
    (4, NULL, 1, 'like'),
    (5, NULL, 2, 'like')
;
```

I want to select and sort post like:

1. Hello => 2 (like)
2. This is title => 1 (like)

Comment: a bit detail will clarify what is your search criteria, like you want to shuffle columns? or sort by title?

Comment: I need sort by total like on each post DESC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perform a self-join, and order on the count of likes:

```
SELECT   id, cnt
FROM     (SELECT id, title
          FROM   posts
          WHERE  title IS NOT NULL) titles
JOIN     (SELECT   post_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     posts
          WHERE    type = 'like'
          GROUP BY post_id) likes ON titles.id = likes.post_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.`title`,COUNT(*),pl.`type` FROM posts p
JOIN posts pl ON pl.`post_id`=p.`id`
GROUP BY p.`id`;
```

LET me know if this work for you.